# Classification using Orange 3

Tags: classification, orange, machine-learning-model

In Orange3 while only using its widgets, without writing Python code, I’ve implemented the following typical machine learning processes

1. Train a training set, (1 file)
2. Validating a validation set (e.g. using Naiive Bayes and kNN), and
3. Testing the model with a test set.(another file)

I keep getting:

> test and train datasets have different target variables

error message. This is despite using exact same formats and names (with different values of course). What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide the workflow screenshot? If I understand right your data are in two separate files (one for training and other for testing)?